# How methods are really accessed in Java concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency

I would like to understand how Java works deep down. All tutorials are at a level that's too high, so I have a few questions:

1. Given this code:

   ```
   class Example {
     public void foo() {
       int number = getRandomNumber();
       System.out.println(number); 
     }
   }
   ```

   Assume that in the example above, the `foo()` method can be accessed by multiple threads. Does every thread have its own and correct value of `number` variable or is it possible for the second thread to modify the value of the first thread (so both of them print the same value)?
2. What would happen if the `int number` was final?

The main thing I want to know is that when I have some initializations (connections, ...) I want to be sure that threads won't be interfering with each other.

Comment: Any reason to name the class `Singleton` ?

Comment: @NarendraPathai just to show that this class exists only in one instance

Comment: @Tomas: as the number of instances doesn't really matter for this question, I took the liberty to rename the class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Has every thread its own and correct value of number variable or is it possible for the second thread to modify the value of the first thread (so both of them print the same value)?

It would be clearer to think of it as *every method invocation* of `foo` has its own `number` variable - it's a local variable within the method. So if this were a recursive method somehow, you could end up with multiple `number` variables at the same time *even in a single thread*, because they'd be different invocations of the method.

No other thread can change the value of a local variable, and you can't change the value for one invocation within any other code, either. It's part of the state of that invocation.

> What would happen if the int number was final?

That would prevent you from changing the value of the variable after initialization, basically.

Comment: +1 for mentioning recursion and showing that even within the same thread you'd have multiple independent copies.

Comment: So when do some concurrency I only need to ensure that access to global variables is synchronized and it'll be ok, right? (simply said)

Comment: @Tomas: Well, it's "any shared state". So that covers instance variables within objects accessed by multiple threads, for example... and don't forget that for class variables, even if a variable is local that doesn't necessarily mean that the object itself isn't being used by multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

**All local members within the methods will be on stack so each method will have its own copy of number variable.**

If number would have been final, still each thread will have its own copy of number.Declaring final will just tell compiler that this variable is not going to change so compiler can do the optimisations on his side.

Answer (score 1):

All variables declared ***within*** a method are stack local. Each thread entering the method will gets its own values for those variables that are entirely invisible to other threads. Declaring the variables final does not change that ... it only affects wether you can access those variables, for example, within anonymous inner classes.

Now, you *could* possibly have some concurrency issues with the values retrieved from the `getRandomNumber` method - depending on its implementation and wether it accesses shared (class) state. But thats theory since you don't show an implementation for it.

For grins and giggles, here's the byte code showing your local method stack:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void myMethod() {
        int tField = 10;
        System.out.println(tField);
    }
}
```

Bytecode:

```
   public void myMethod();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=1         // <-- Each thread gets its own
         0: bipush        10
         2: istore_1      
         3: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
         6: iload_1       
         7: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
        10: return
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Each thread will have its own copy of local variable because each one will have its own call stack .
2. You will not be able to assign any other value to that final variable elsewhere in the method .

Answer (score 1):

`number` is a local variable, not a field, so it lives on the stack and every thread gets its own version.

You need to think about thread-safety only for shared state, i.e. data that gets allocated on the heap, such as an object's fields.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to both your questions regarding `number` - each thread would have their own variable - no thread would be able to alter any other threads local variable, regardless of whether it was `final` or not.

All local variables are unique - there is a copy on the stack for each thread calling the method.

Answer (score 1):

Each thread has its own call stack.

Upon that call stack there are stack frames. One for each method invocation.

Inside that stack frame are the local variables (among other things).

So yes, every invocation of the `foo` method has its own `number` variable.

Having a `final` local variable doesn't change that fundamentally.

Answer (score 1):

As per sample code

1. In method context thread concurrently accessing `foo()` will have own stack for execution of `foo()` method. Local variables are not shared.
2. Nothing as far as concurrent access is concern.Having it final will make sure that inside `foo()` method number value is not updated.

If objects or static variables are shared across multiple threads then concurrency scenario would arise and threads might interfere.

Below if objects of class XYZ are shared across two threads, number updated by one thread might get printed by second thread.

```
 class XYZ {
static int number = 0;
  public void foo() {
    number = getRandomNumber();
    System.out.println(number); 
  }
}
```